# Reading Excel: evaluation error with zip file cannot be opened

Tags: r, readxl

I get the following error when I want to read a new excel file into my old projects:

> "Reading Excel: evaluation error with zip file cannot be opened"

I can open the same file in a new project. What could be the difference?

Does the creation date of the file have any significance for `readxl` package?

Comment: The creation date of the file has *no* significance. The error is elsewhere. The error message is misleading, it just means that the file can’t be found. You’re executing your code in the wrong folder.

Comment: Hi Esad! Please include information about the code, session and IDE/text editor you are using. Also, can you please share the path used in each session? That should make it easy for other people understand your problem.  I don't think there's a problem with `readxl`. Probably there's some issue with the path/working directory defined in each situation. There's a question similar to yours here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619585/reading-excel-evaluation-error-with-zip-file-file-xlsx-cannot-be-opened/63778313